# Calculate average for column value within a time interval

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe

```
                        id      timestamp               data    gradient        Start
timestamp                                       
2020-01-15 06:12:49.213 40250   2020-01-15 06:12:49.213 20.0    0.00373         NaN 
2020-01-15 06:12:49.313 40251   2020-01-15 06:12:49.313 19.5    0.00354         0.0 
2020-01-15 08:05:10.083 40256   2020-01-15 08:05:10.083 20.0    0.00020         1.0 
2020-01-15 08:05:10.183 40257   2020-01-15 08:05:10.183 20.5    -0.00440        0.0
                            ...
2020-01-31 09:01:50.993 40310   2020-01-31 09:01:50.993 21.0    0.55473         1.0
2020-01-31 09:01:51.093 40311   2020-01-31 09:01:51.093 21.5    0.00589         0.0
                            ...
```

I want to find the average of `data` that lie between `start_time ==1` and `30 seconds` later.

Reproducible example:

```
d = {'timestamp':["2020-01-15 06:12:49.213", "2020-01-15 06:12:49.313", "2020-01-15 08:05:10.083", "2020-01-15 08:05:10.183", "2020-01-15 09:01:50.993", "2020-01-15 09:01:51.093", "2020-01-15 09:51:01.890", "2020-01-15 09:51:01.990", "2020-01-15 10:40:59.657", "2020-01-15 10:40:59.757", "2020-01-15 10:42:55.693", "2020-01-15 10:42:55.793", "2020-01-15 10:45:35.767", "2020-01-15 10:45:35.867", "2020-01-15 10:45:46.770", "2020-01-15 10:45:46.870", "2020-01-15 10:47:19.783", "2020-01-15 10:47:19.883", "2020-01-15 10:47:22.787"],
'data': [20.0, 19.5, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0, 22.5, 23.0, 23.5, 23.0, 22.5, 23.0, 23.5, 24.0, 24.5, 25.0, 25.5, 26], 
'gradient': [NaN, NaN, 0.000000, 0.000148, 0.000294, 0.000294, 0.000339, 0.000339, 0.000334, 0.000334, 0.000000, -0.008618, 0.000000, 0.006247, 0.090884, 0.090884, 0.010751, 0.010751, 0.332889],
'Start': [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Expected output:

```
start_time               end_time                   Average
2020-01-15 08:05:10.083  2020-01-15 09:01:51.093    20.25  = average of (20.0, 20.5)
2020-01-15 10:45:35.767  2020-01-15 10:45:35.767    23.75  = average of (23.0, 23.5, 24.0, 24.5)
```

---

Edit:

Using @jezrael's code:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['g'] = df['Start'].cumsum()

df1 = df[df['g'].ne(0)].copy()
#
s = df1.groupby('g')['timestamp'].transform('first')
df1 = df1[df1['timestamp'].between(s, s + pd.Timedelta(30, 's'))]
#
df2 = df1.groupby('g').agg(start_time=('timestamp','first'),
                           end_time=('timestamp','last'),
                           Average=('data','mean')).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
```

I obtained output 
[image]

It seems that some start and end time are very close, around 0.1second difference. This is a fault in the data collecting device which recorded 2 data points every time, instead of 1, and the data points have a `0.5` difference for `data`. In addition, there are very few data points, which caused the the start and end time to be very close for a `30 seconds` time interval. My question is, is it possible if we forward fill the sample? So that there is more data to measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get first `timestamp` per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) then compare by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['g'] = df['Start'].cumsum()

df1 = df[df['g'].ne(0)].copy()
#
s = df1.groupby('g')['timestamp'].transform('first')
df1 = df1[df1['timestamp'].between(s, s + pd.Timedelta(30, 's'))]
#
df2 = df1.groupby('g').agg(start_time=('timestamp','first'),
                           end_time=('timestamp','last'),
                           Average=('data','mean')).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
               start_time                end_time  Average
0 2020-01-15 08:05:10.083 2020-01-15 08:05:10.183    20.25
1 2020-01-15 10:45:35.767 2020-01-15 10:45:46.870    23.75
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

start_time_list = []
end_time_list = []
average_list = []

for start_ind in df[df['Start'] == 1].index:   
    end_ind = np.where(df['timestamp'] <= df.iloc[start_ind]['timestamp'] + pd.to_timedelta(30, unit = 's'))[0][-1] + 1    
    average = df['data'].iloc[start_ind:end_ind].mean()

    start_time_list.append(df.iloc[start_ind]['timestamp'])
    end_time_list.append(df.iloc[end_ind]['timestamp'])
    average_list.append(average)

output = pd.DataFrame({"start_time":start_time_list,
                       "end_time":end_time_list,
                       "average":average_list})
```

Comment: Hi Gilseung, thanks for your answer. But it returned `TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key` for ` end_ind = np.where(df['timestamp'] <= df.iloc[start_ind]['timestamp'] + pd.to_timedelta(30, unit = 's'))[0][-1] + 1`